# Can you do arithmetic on a char* pointing at another object

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

This is a common way to read the bytes of an trivially copyable object

```
Object obj;
auto p = reinterpret_cast<char*>(&obj);
for(size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(obj); i++)
    consume(p[i]);
```

The problem isn't with strict-aliasing, `char*` is allowed to alias anything. The problem is with this passage from [[expr.add]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/expr.add#4)

> When an expression that has integral type is added to or subtracted from a pointer, the result has the type of the pointer operand. If the expression `P` points to element `x[i]` of an array object `x` with `n` elements, the expressions `P + J` and `J + P` (where `J` has the value `j`) point to the (possibly-hypothetical) element `x[i + j]` if `0 ≤ i + j ≤ n`; otherwise, the behavior is undefined. Likewise, the expression `P - J` points to the (possibly-hypothetical) element `x[i − j]` if `0 ≤ i − j ≤ n`; otherwise, the behavior is undefined.

Where hypothetical element refers to

> A pointer past the last element of an array `x` of `n` elements is considered to be equivalent to a pointer to a hypothetical element `x[n]` for this purpose

Which is to say, it is only legal if the arithmetic is on a pointer pointing at an array, and the result is still within its range.

However, there is clearly no `char[sizeof(Object)]` here, can we do arithmetic on that pointer?

Note that a legal solution to reading bytes of an object is to `std::memcpy` the object. But if that is the *only* solution, it begs to ask, why allow `char*` aliasing if you can barely do anything with it?

Comment: Why is lack-of-element-one-past-the-end a concern?  Surely that's true for **all** uses of pointers and arrays?

Comment: `unsigned char*` arithmetic, certainly. `char*` I don't think you can.

Comment: A long time ago [in a galaxy far, far away] there was no `void*` type and `char*` was used instead.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth The passage is talking about you may only do arithmetic on the elements of an array, with the one past the end treated as a hypothetical element. I'm assuming this is what you're asking about?

Comment: @Bathsheba Why is `unsigned char*` any different?

Comment: I guess I'm just not sure I understand what you're seeing as a problem here.  Your argument ends on "*there is clearly no char[sizeof(Object)] here, can we do arithmetic on that pointer?*", but I'm not sure why you see that as a concern.

Comment: Whereas it should work in practice, OP asks if it is pedantically UB or not.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth Updated to clarify

Comment: I'm still not sure why the "past the end" thing is the crux here.  By definition, even "real" arrays don't have elements past the end!  (If, however, you have a general concern about whether it's valid to treat an object as a `char` array, then I get that.)

Comment: It seems you have invented the problem that does not exist really. E.g. you may write `char* p = 0x1234;` and use `p` in expressions (but not for dereferencing of course).

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth The "past the end" thing is just to be complete. The problem is with there being no `char[]` and we're doing arithmetic on a `char*`

Comment: @KonstantinL `char* p = 0x1234; p += 100;` is illegal by the passage. What do you mean by _"A pointer is not coupled so tight with an [potentially] underlying object."_?

Comment: given that we're in pedantic mode, only trivially copyable and standard layout types are guaranteed to occupy contiguous bytes of storage (and to be memcopied), so you may clarify which *Object* types your question's about ...

Comment: `char* p = 0x1234; p += 100;` is not illegal as no `N` of `char[N]` defined.

Comment: @KonstantinL It violates the precondition _`P` points to element `x[i]` of an array object_

Comment: Yep, _precondition_, not the rule.

Comment: @geza That question is about fetching a value form pointer, while this question is about just pointer arithmetic.

Comment: @ivaigult: no, that question is about arithmetic as well.

Comment: @geza Yeah that's a dupe

Answer (score 1):

The pointer arithmetic should be legal according to the quotes. An `Object` instance `obj` can be viewed as `char[sizeof(Object)]`. So, it is an array of `n` elements (note that `n` is `sizeof(Object)`). Standard allows to do pointer arithmetic in bounds of this array *plus one hypothetical element beyond the bounds of this array*. This is due to *less or equal* sign in the

> 0 ≤ i + j ≤ n

expression.

Literally, `reinterpret_cast<char*> (&obj) + sizeof(Object)` is fine because it points to hypothetical element `a[j]`, where `j = sizeof(Object)` and it is *less or equal* than size of the array, which is `sizeof(Object)`.

So, the answer is yes.

Otherwise `std::end` for arrays would be UB.

Comment: Where exactly does it say the `obj` can be "viewed" as `char[sizeof(Object)]`?

Comment: @Passer By by viewed aliased was meant.

Comment: __Where__ exactly is it said that that is allowed?

Comment: @PasserBy [basic.types](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/basic.types#def:object_representation)

Comment: `N` `unsigned char` is not equal to `unsigned char[N]`, even if they are right beside each other. Also, you should put that in the answer.

Comment: There is also another paragraph _"For any object (other than a base-class subobject) of trivially copyable type `T`, whether or not the object holds a valid value of type `T`, the underlying bytes making up the object can be copied into an array of `char`, `unsigned char`, or `std​::​byte`"_. Which made no mention of directly reading the object's value representation as if it was an array.