# Is accessing "object representation" using the constructor string_view(const char*, size_type) defined char aliasing or undefined behavior?

Tags: c++, c++11, strict-aliasing, type-punning, string-view

Let we have this object

```
constexpr uint64_t lil_endian = 0x65'6e'64'69'61'6e; // 00en dian
    // a.k.a. Clockwise Rotated Endian which allocates like
    // char[8] = { 'n','a','i','d','n','e','\0','\0' }
```

It is believed that `memcpy` is there also to help pun type like this

```
char arr[sizeof(lil_endian)];
auto p1 = std::addressof(arr[0]);
std::memcpy(p1, &lil_endian, sizeof(lil_endian) ); // defined?
auto sv1 = std::string_view(p1, sizeof(lil_endian) );
std::string str1(sv1.crbegin()+2, sv1.crend() );
std::cout << str1        << "\n"
          << str1.size() << "\n";
```

everything is like expected:

```
endian
6
```

---

The matter of fact is that even with `string_view` alone, we access the object by `char` anyway, which `char` is one of the allowance three `char`, `unsigned char`, `std::byte` aliases.

So can we just skip the redundant copy part of the code, like this?

```
auto p2 = reinterpret_cast<const char *>
                ( &lil_endian );
auto sv2 = std::string_view(p2, sizeof(lil_endian) ); // is this "char" aliasing?
std::string str2(sv2.crbegin()+2, sv2.crend() );   
std::cout << str2        << "\n"
          << str2.size() << "\n";

}
```

output:

```
endian
6
```

Is the constructor string_view(const char*, size_type) "char" aliasing by strict aliasing [([basic.val]/11)](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.lval#11) -- § 8.2.1 ¶ 11 in [N4713 page 82](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/n4713.pdf#page=90)

[godbolt](https://godbolt.org/g/ww5Hcq)

[wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/8wPAXq4oc4puDSZt)

Comment: Do you not see the explicit exception granted to `char`, `unsigned char` and `std::byte`? It's right there in the section you link to at 11.8. Aliasing through a `const char*` is perfectly legal and well defined.

Comment: You seem to have answered your question in the question. Which part of this are you unsure of? Whether `string_view` internally is just a `const char*` or whether access via `const char*` is *really* access via `char`?

Comment: @NathanErnst I'm not sure. Because last month the both answers of [47921786](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47921786) didn't confirm that this is defined.

Comment: @Barry You may flag this as duplicate but the thing is that the both answers of [47921786](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47921786) didn't confirm that this is defined.

Comment: @sandthorn What? I'm trying to understand what your *question* is. What is the source of confusion?

Comment: @Barry The source of my confusion is that both answers of [47921786](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47921786) seem **not certained enough** to say like "it's okey to reinterpret pointer to char then wrap around `trivially_copyable`s with `string_view` constructor". Well, if you think it's pretty okey, you can write some answer to this or to [47921786](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47921786) or even both! ...would be great. I guess we just need an expert to confirm us about this.